# Symfony2 - leftjoin - order by - count on right

Tags: symfony, count, left-join

I have 3 entities

- "Ejuridique" with "onetomany" relation with
- "Project" with "onetomany" relation with
- "Photo"

**I need a list of each "Ejuridique" with his first project and with the first picture of this first project, like this.**

ejuridique1 - project1_1 - photo1

ejuridique2 - project2_1 - photo1

ejuridique3 - project3_1 - photo1

**AND, I want to order this "Ejuridique" list in function of the total of the projects of the "Ejuridique"**

ejuridique2 - project2_1 - photo1   (3 projects in total)

ejuridique1 - project1_1 - photo1   (2 projects in total)

ejuridique3 - project3_1 - photo1   (1 projects in total)

So I have to make cascading leftjoin and order the results in function of the count of the projects of each "Ejuridique"

With querybuilder, I receive an error when I add the count after the leftjoins.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What was the issue with `count(pr.id) as count1` ? It might be better to use `getScalarResult()` instead of `getResult()`. I also guess you need to build your query by `COUNT(DISTINCT(pr.id))` if I understood your question

Comment: the error: "Key 'projetcs' for array with keys "0, count1" does not exist ". Some of the "ejuridiques" do not have projects. So I assume that it can not count something that do not exist? Beside of this, the suggestion of kanalkyte to do it in native sql seems to be a good one. But, I am busy of reading the documentation for the moment (even if it does not seem to be very explicit!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `ResultSetMap`. DB Query Builder only works when you get either scalar (numeric) value or entities. Doesn't work when you want to retrieve both of them (i.e : ejuridique + project count in your case).

You can find more informations by folowing this link [Doctrine Documentation : native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

**EDIT**

I used your revision history from your question to find out what you already wrote since you deleted it. The flowing code won't work obviously but I think you can't get both the first photo of the first project and the count.

```
public function getProjectCount()
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);

    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Ejuridique', 'e');
    $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Projects', 'pr', 'e', 'projets', array('id' => 'projet_id'));
    $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Photos', 'ph', 'pr', 'photos', array('id' => 'photos_id'));        
    $rsm->addScalarResult('ProjectCount', 'ProjectCount');   

    $sql = 'SELECT e.nom, count(pr.id) as ProjectCount
            FROM ejuridique e 
            INNER JOIN Project pr ON e.id = pr.ejuridique_id
            INNER JOIN Photo ph ON pr.id = ph.projet_id
            WHERE e.id = :eid
            GROUP BY project.id,
            ORDER BY ProjectCount';

    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $qb);
    $query->setParameter('eid', 535);
    $query->setParameter('position_pr', 1);
    $query->setParameter('position_ph', 1);

    return $ejuridiques = $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I have adapted my question with an attempt of ResultSetMap.

Comment: I managed to find the solution a little bit like yours, but yours is still better because easier and simplified. Perfect!